If I want to render the tables of a PowerPoint presentation do I have to open it to render it?
I have a PowerPoint template where I have a bunch of graphs that shall be filled with some variables. Those I have saved in a CSV file. For each row of that CSV I create/fill one powerpoint. I modify the tables in a ppt by accessing the embedded excel tables. I unzip them, fill the values, and zip again - which works fine. The problem is, apparently, the graphs don't automatically update/render when you change those tables programmatically. I set up Windows on my Mac and wrote a render script with win32com. That, however, does not allow me to render stuff without opening the ppt (I will upload the script if that matters). Every table there now opens, fills, closes, for every ppt. With 20 tables and 10000 presentations to generate I would have to wait 3 days constantly computing.
Which way might work better? I am mostly proficient in Python on Mac but am open to using other stuff. I have used C# before and even a VBA solution would be ok.
